# Isomorphism between two $K$-algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Consider a field extension $L\subseteq K$ and suppose that $I=(f_1,\ldots,f_m)$ is an ideal of $L[T_1,\ldots,T_n]$. Denote with $I^e\subseteq K[T_1,\ldots,T_n] $ the extended ideal of $I$ through the canonical immersion $\iota:L[T_1,\ldots,T_n]\longrightarrow K[T_1,\ldots,T_n] $. Now I have to prove the following isomorphism of $K$-algebras

$$ \frac{L[T_1,\ldots,T_n]}{I}\otimes_L K\cong \frac{K[T_1,\ldots,T_n]}{I^e}  $$

Maybe an explicit isomorphism can be given by $I+g\otimes a\longmapsto I^e +ag $, but I have problems to find the inverse. Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: First try without the ideals: $L[T_1,\dots,T_n] \otimes_L K \cong K[T_1,\dots,T_n]$ using exactly your idea. Note that every term of $K[T_1,\dots,T_n]$ (i.e., a monomial with coefficient $1$) is also a term of $L[T_1,\dots,T_n]$; use that to build an explicit inverse. (If you really want; it might be easier just to prove injectivity and surjectivity directly). After that, look at the quotient rings.

Comment: I'd suggest to try without variables: Let $\phi: B \to A$ be ring homomorphism, and $I \subset B$ an ideal. Describe a natural isomorphism $A/I^e \simeq A \otimes_B (B/I)$. Hint is to use right exactness of $A \otimes_B (\cdot)$ on $I \to B \to B/I \to 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, note that $L[T_1,\ldots,T_n]$ is a $L$-vector space. You can see pretty easily that $L[T_1,\ldots,T_n]\otimes_L K\cong K[T_1,\ldots,T_n]$. Similarly, it should be clear that $I^e = I\otimes_L K$.

Consider the exact sequence of $L$-modules (ie, $L$-vector spaces)
$$0\rightarrow I\rightarrow L[T_1,\ldots,T_n]\rightarrow L[T_1,\ldots,T_n]/I\rightarrow 0$$
Since $K$ is a flat $L$-module (any module over a field is flat), you get an exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow I\otimes_L K\rightarrow L[T_1,\ldots,T_n]\otimes_L K\rightarrow (L[T_1,\ldots,T_n]/I)\otimes_L K\rightarrow 0$$
ie, you have an exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow I^e\rightarrow K[T_1,\ldots,T_n]\rightarrow(L[T_1,\ldots,T_n]/I)\otimes_L K \rightarrow 0$$
which presents $(L[T_1,\ldots,T_n]/I)\otimes_L K$ as a quotient of $K[T_1,\ldots,T_n]$ by $I^e$.